# Constexpr constructor to create fixed_string and wrap std::array<char, L>

Tags: c++, string, constexpr

I'm trying to make a constexpr fixed_string class and I'm having issues with the constructor being able to convert `const char*` and `const char(&)[L]` to `std::array<char, Length>`.

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename char_type, std::size_t Length>
struct fixed_string
{
    constexpr fixed_string(const char_type* value)
    :
        mData{reinterpret_cast<char_type[std::char_traits<const char_type>::length(value)]>(value)}
    {
    }

    template <std::size_t L>
    constexpr fixed_string(const char_type (&value)[L])
    :
        mData{{value}}
    {
        static_assert(L <= Length);
    }

    std::array<char_type, Length> mData;
};

template <typename char_type, std::size_t L>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, fixed_string<char_type, L> s)
{
    for (auto c : s.mData)
        os << c;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    constexpr char hello[] = "hello";
    std::cout << fixed_string<const char, 6>{hello} << std::endl;
    std::cout << fixed_string<const char, 6>{"hello"} << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Both my constructor methods are incorrect currently. Error messages include:

```
10:15: error: invalid cast from type 'const char*' to type 'char [(<anonymous> + 1)]'
   10 |         mData{reinterpret_cast<char_type[std::char_traits<const char_type>::length(value)]>(value)}
```

```
17:22: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
   17 |         mData{{value}}
```

I'm using `std::char_traits<char>::length` because it is constexpr. Maybe this could be unsafe if `strlen(value) > Length` but hopefully the construction of std::array could solve that?

I'm aware I can create a fixed_string class using a std::copy at runtime. I'm hoping that I can improve upon that to make it constexpr. I've been compiling with gcc10.2 --std=c++17.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: Added template char_type to show I don't necessarily care about the type of char.

Comment: I don't have time to check at the moment (sorry), but I do notice that the error involves casting from `const` to non-const. If it is your intent to cast away the `const`-ness *of the input,* you may want to justify that intent and explain how it is compatible with the constructor being `constexpr`.

Comment: @JaMiT good point, my intention is not to cast away the constness but to keep it. I can make everything const char and that will be fine.

Comment: If my `fixed_string` is constexpr I don't mind that the std::array uses a const char type.

Comment: Here's a simple fixed string that works for example: https://github.com/morganstanley/binlog/blob/main/include/mserialize/cx_string.hpp

Comment: @erenon Ooh this looks nice! Would be cool if this worked with std::array. One difference is I don't require constexpr accessors like the comment says in that code.

Comment: @mojo1mojo2 I think you missed the point by adding a template parameter. That made the code more complicated without addressing the issue. Your first constructor still takes a pointer to a `const` something and tries to reinterpret it as an array of that something without the `const` qualifier. Same problem, only hidden now because you've forced the "something" to be `const char`, making `const char_type` and `char_type` the same type. (I now think your current issue is not this, but you might see something new go wrong if you instantiate `fixed_string<char, 6>`.)

Comment: Rather than introduce an unneeded template parameter, why not just make your code consistent with regards to `const` qualification? Adding a single `const` in your original code could have done this: `reinterpret_cast<const char[std::char_traits<const char>::length(value)]>(value)`.

Comment: I did a few tests, and it looks like you might have two errors. Which is more interesting -- the problem with the cast or the problem with aggregate initialization? The error on the cast can be isolated by by changing the initialization of `mData` to `mData{}` then adding the following line to the body of the constructor: `(void)reinterpret_cast<char_type[std::char_traits<const char_type>::length(value)]>(value);`. The initialization error might be isolated by instead changing the cast to `reinterpret_cast<char_type(&)[std::char_traits<const char_type>::length(value)]>(value)`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for you help.

I have tried the second point and still get the same error of `error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'`. It has issues with the initialisation list of std::array I believe so I'm not sure how to cast `const char*` to that.

I'm not sure what you mean by the first point. That statement won't do anything on it's own other than reinterpret_cast value? It "compiles" but it doesn't do anything useful with mData set to {}.