# Is it possible with C++20 to have a constexpr function return a tuple of types that have static constexpr array's with a value passed though a macro?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, constexpr-function

After two or three days of trying, I had to give up and wrote a "minimal" test case I hope demonstrates the problem.

What I need is a method to convert string-literals, that are passed as macro arguments without quotes, into strings (catenated with a prefix) that are accessible in a constexpr environment (see https://wandbox.org/permlink/Cr6j6fXemsQRycHI for the *Real Code*(tm)); that means, they (the macro arguments) should be stringified and then converted into either a type (e.g. template`<... 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ...>`) or into a `static constexpr array<char, N>` of a unique type that is passed instead (e.g template`<... A<1> ...>`, where `A<1>::str` is a `static constexpr array<char, 6>` with the contents `'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'`.

I strongly prefer the latter, and the former only if the latter isn't possible.

To demonstrate the exact problem/requirement in a short test case I came up with the following:

Some headers...

```
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

Then for the sake of demonstrating how the end-result should behave:

```
template<int I>
struct A;

template<>
struct A<0>
{
  static constexpr auto str = std::to_array("abc"); // The string-literal "abc" may NOT appear here.
                                                    // The code should work for any macro argument
                                                    // (though for this test case you may assume all
                                                    // string literals are three chars).
};

template<>
struct A<1>
{
  static constexpr auto str = std::to_array("def"); // Same.
};

constexpr auto f(char const* s0, char const* s1)
{
  return std::tuple<
    A<0>, // The 0, because this is the first argument, makes the type (A<0>) unique, and therefore
          // a static constexpr can be part of that unique type that contains the string s0.
    A<1>  // Same for 1 and A<1>.
  >{};
}

#define STR(arg) #arg
#define STRINGIFY(arg) STR(arg)

#define MEMBER(arg) STRINGIFY(arg)
```

And finally the rest of the code that hopefully enforces everything I *need*
the above to do:

```
//=====================================================================
// NOTHING BELOW THIS LINE MAY BE CHANGED.

struct C
{
  static constexpr auto x = f(
    MEMBER(abc),
    MEMBER(def)
  );
};

int main()
{
  // The type returned by f() is a tuple.
  using xt = decltype(C::x);
  
  // Each element of that tuple must be a type...
  using e0 = std::tuple_element_t<0, xt>;
  using e1 = std::tuple_element_t<1, xt>;

  // ... that defines a static constexpr array<> 'str'.
  constexpr std::array a0 = e0::str;
  constexpr std::array a1 = e1::str;
  
  std::string s0{a0.begin(), a0.end()};    // Note that the array str includes a terminating zero. 
  std::string s1{a1.begin(), a1.end()};

  std::cout << "s0 = \"" << s0 << "\"\n";
  std::cout << "s1 = \"" << s1 << "\"\n";

  // ... that has the value that was passed as macro argument.
  assert(s0.compare("abc") && s0[3] == '\0');
  assert(s1.compare("def") && s1[3] == '\0');
}
```

The second code block needs some obvious fixes:

1. it contains hard-coded strings for `"abc"` and `"def"` which are supposed to come from the macro arguments passed to `MEMBER` at the top of the third block.
2. The arguments passed to `f()` are not even used.

The idea here is that each argument of `f()` results in an element type of the returned tuple - for the sake of simplicity I made this fixed: just two arguments.

Each element of the tuple is guaranteed to be a unique type, but that uniqueness depends on the fact that it contains an integer template parameter that is incremented for each argument; in the real code the uniqueness is guaranteed further by only invoking `f()` once per unique (user) class (`C` above); but since this in this test case `f()` is only invoked once anyway, I left that out. Literally returning `std::tuple<A<0>, A<1>>` is therefore in theory the goal.

Since each tuple element is a unique type, in theory they can contain a `static constexpr array` with the argument that was passed to the `MEMBER` macro as their content. However, I don't see how this is possible to achieve.

What I really need is "encoded" in the third block: if that works for any identifier string (i.e. no spaces, if that matters) as macro arguments (after also replacing the test strings at the end), then the interface of block two should teach me how to do this.

The complete test case can be found online here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vyPK9qktAzcdP3wt

EDIT

Thanks to pnda's solution, we now have an answer; I just made some tiny changes so that the third code block can stay as-is. With the following as second code block it compiles and works!

```
struct TemplateStringLiteral {
  std::array<char, N> chars;
  consteval TemplateStringLiteral(std::array<char, N> literal) : chars(literal) { }
};

template<TemplateStringLiteral literal>
struct B {
  static constexpr auto str = literal.chars;
};

template<TemplateStringLiteral s>
struct Wrap
{
};

template <TemplateStringLiteral s0, TemplateStringLiteral s1>
consteval auto f(Wrap<s0>, Wrap<s1>)
{
  return std::tuple<
    B<s0>,
    B<s1>
  >{};
}

#define STR(arg) #arg
#define STRINGIFY(arg) STR(arg)
#define MEMBER(arg) Wrap<std::to_array(STRINGIFY(arg))>{}
```

Comment: Woah, this reads like a development log. Could you please compact it to a focused question? Why do you want to use macros? What is the actual underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @JHBonarius I spent literally a whole day to make it this short; no way I can make it even compacter :/. Have a look at the first link (the Real Code), which in fact is also already an extraction from the real project to something that fits on wandbox :/.

Comment: @JHBonarius I don't WANT to use macros, but I am not against it. It will not limit you in coming up with a solution: since you're free to change the macro to anything you want, it gives a lot of freedom. For example, you could make it return a complex type, instead of a `char const*` or do even other magic. The main reason I am using it here is because this is the current interface of the Real Code and *that* uses a macro because I already have eight places where this interface is used and I did get completely nuts of making the same changes in eight different places every time I wanted to try

Comment: a new approach :/.  This gives simply the most flexibility - certainly while the API is still changing on an hourly basis.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033110/passing-a-string-literal-as-a-type-argument-to-a-class-template

Comment: @JHBonarius Thanks! It just never occurred to me that I really had to approach this by passing a string literal as a template parameter, until pnda showed me that that leads to a solution. Other related questions (without accepted answers) are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195445/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67714941/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to store a string literal inside of a template argument. I wrote a class that does exactly that a year or so ago. This allows the tuple creation to be constexpr while also offering a quite nice way of passing the strings. This class can also be used to differentiate between two types using a string without modifying the rest of the templated class, which is very useful if you're using typeless handles.

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
struct TemplateStringLiteral {
    char chars[N];

    consteval TemplateStringLiteral(const char (&literal)[N]) {
        // Does anyone know of a replacement of std::copy_n? It's from
        // <algorithm>.
        std::copy_n(literal, N, chars);
    }
};
```

Using this class, it is possible for us to pass the tuple creation this class with a string literal attached to it. This does, sadly, slightly modify your `C::x` from using the `MEMBER` define for the function arguments to using the `MEMBER` define for the template arguments. It is also perfectly possible to just use normal string literals in the template arguments.

```cpp
struct C
{
    // Essentially just f<"abc", "def">();
    static constexpr auto x = f<MEMBER(abc), MEMBER(def)>();
};
```

For the function f we now want to take the parameters as template arguments. So we'll now use the `TemplateStringLiteral` class to take in the string literals, while also making it a template parameter pack to allow for any amount of parameters.

```cpp
template <TemplateStringLiteral... literal>
consteval auto f() {
    // I'll talk about A in a second. It just holds our string
    return std::tuple<A<literal>...> {};
}
```

Now that we've got a function `f` that can create a `std::tuple` from some amount of string literals passed in through template parameters, we'll just need to define the class A that the tuple holds. We can't pass the string literals directly to `std::tuple` as it does not have something akin to `TemplateStringLiteral`. Defining class A is very simple, as we only need a `str` field holding our string literal.

```cpp
template<TemplateStringLiteral literal>
struct A {
    static constexpr auto str = std::to_array(literal.chars);
};
```

So, using TemplateStringLiteral we've got an implementation that's about 16 lines of C++ and is pretty easily understandable imo.

Comment: Awesome! I also got it to work now without changing `C::x` - or anything in the third block: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3pJckkBj3lo2NrL4  Thank you!